# How to remove "XXX is an application downloaded from the internet. are you sure you want to open it" at start up?

Tags: macos, applications

Everytime I restart my mac, a pop up shows up telling me that "TunesGoWatch is an application downloaded from the internet. are you sure you want to open it?".

I don't know where this message comes from and I'm not sure how to get rid of it forever (I downloaded this app very long ago but uninstalled it) It pop ups automatically at start up.

Comment: Ugh... Wondershare :/ There will be leftovers

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The app is almost certainly in your Login items.

To check and remove it, do this:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences > Users & Groups
2. Make sure your User Account is selected at top left
3. Click on the Login Items tab
4. Look for an item called *TunesGoWatch* (or something else that could be triggering this) in the list of login items
5. Now remove this item by clicking on its name (so it's highlighted) and then clicking on the minus <kbd>-</kbd> button
6. Once it's removed, exit System Preferences
7. Restart your Mac to test to see if the problem still persists

Answer (score 12):

Best way I can think of to get rid of Wondershare is to do a thorough search & trash everything you can find with that name & also, while you're at it, iSkySoft who appear to be closely associated & equally insidious.

First get hold of [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) from the App Store - freeware.

Set it to search the entire boot drive for wondershare, case insensitive, files & folders & also invisible items [Spotlight won't find these]

Any results you get for Wondershare just throw in the Trash.

Repeat for iskysoft, just in case.

Also repeat for 'tunesgowatch' just in case.

Empty Trash, reboot, wave bye bye, don't go near them again.

Comment: Welcome - make sure you do it even if Monomeeth's answer worked. They are both really insidious companies & leave all kinds of "what the heck does that do?" stuff running in the background on your machine.